# Deleted Github Repo made me lose Xcode files

Tags: xcode, git, github

I'm new to GitHub Desktop and I was working on a project that I was trying to push to the remote server but it wasn't working.

Now Xcode has this source control that I have committed to my local repository I guess?? But now I've deleted my Repository from Github Desktop because it wasn't pushing all the files into the remote server.

This made me lose my project, and now I do not know where to find it. I was hoping that there is a way I can get the files back from the local git from my Mac

Comment: If you use Time Machine everything that was on your Mac an hour before the deletion is recoverable.

Comment: And if the project folder is still a git repo then everything committed is still there.

Comment: how do I use the time machine? and it was GitHub that deleted my Xcode files im not sure if it would save into my Mac. but I did commit the files before deleting it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I did commit the files before deleting it though.

Then, in command line, check the output of `git log` or `git reflog`: you should see your commit.

A `git checkout <old-commit> -- .` (or, with Git 2.23+, `git restore -s=<oldCommit> -SW :\`) would restore what you have committed.
Restore locally at least: you would still need to push it to GitHub.
Then you can reopen XCode.